# How to change fixed selected box value dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have 3 select box. Each select box value must change dynamically.

I want to change the 2nd and 3rd select box value depending on 1st select box. 
With jQuery easy way fixed.

```
Commerce->English
Arts->Gujarati
science->French

Commerce->IP    
Arts->Computer
Science->java
```

Please see the html here  http://jsfiddle.net/j2pCJ/1/

THIS IS SAMPLE 2 BOX AND I WANT TO 3 BOX http://jsfiddle.net/sabithpocker/fRuhn/

JQUERY CODE IS HERE

```
$("#select1").change(function() { 
if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
    /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
    $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
    } 
var id = $(this).val();
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
$('#select2').html(options);
});
```

Comment: ***depend on 1st select box*** how does it depend?

Comment: means dynamic change if i select commerce from 1st select box 2nd select box and 3rd select box value must change dynamic.

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried that didn't work.

Comment: @j08691 - I don't think so. That is where "Stack Overflow crowd  sourcing" comes in. =/

Comment: @vivek change to what..? update the proper info in your question or it's likely to be closed.

Comment: @j08691 i'm not jquer expert :(

Comment: @vivek - start here http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: @TJ i want to change second box value based on 1st box if user select commerce from 1st box then 2nd box automatically display English.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sabithpocker/fRuhn/ this can help you for better understanding

Comment: @vivek everybody won't read the comments. Update your question and add the info. Your question already have enough close votes...

Comment: I UPDATED QUESTION PLEASE CHECK DONT CLOSE THIS QUESTION IT IS VERY URGENT WORK FOR ME :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not believe what you want is simple like this:

```
var secondSelect = $("select[name='2ndbox']");
var thirdSelect = $("select[name='3rdbox']");
var secondOptions = secondSelect.children('option');
var thirdOptions = thirdSelect.children('option');

$("select[name='1stbox']").change(function(){     
  var selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
  secondOptions.filter(function(i){ return i == selectedIndex})
               .appendTo(secondSelect.empty());
  thirdOptions.filter(function(i){ return i == selectedIndex})
              .appendTo(thirdSelect.empty());
}).change();
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/j2pCJ/4/)

Note that using `filter` is just a general way to implement it, in your specific case, looks like we can just use the `.eq()` method like this:

```
secondOptions.eq(selectedIndex).appendTo(secondSelect.empty());
```

Comment: Note If I still misunderstand your problem, just leave some comment and I'll fix it.

Comment: very very thank you for your time but i want to show only related value like this 

http://jsfiddle.net/sabithpocker/fRuhn/

if user select commerce then display only english and IP

Comment: @vivek do you mean the `english` should be displayed on the second select, `IP` should be displayed on the third select and those 2 selects (2nd and 3rd) should not have any other options to select? It's strange indeed because that's not the purpose of select element (it should have more than 1 option).

Comment: yes i want to change both select box value like this 
is user select Commerce from 1st box then second box will display only english and 3rd will display only IP

Commerce->English
Commerce->IP

Comment: @vivek I have a feeling that that is not actually the case (in reallity). So the code I updated may not be relevant for the actual use case.

Comment: you saves my life this is very good :) working great :) thank you for your answer and valuable time for me thanx for heart